# React Big Calendar Row size change?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Does anyone knows how to change the height of the react big calendar when we add more than one event in a day cell. Big help .Thank you in adnvance

Answer (score 3):

This style change will help auto row height for react-big-calendar.

```css
.rbc-month-row {
  display: inline-table !important;
  flex: 0 0 0 !important;
  min-height: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.rbc-timeslot-group {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```